# A method not working after fragment orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Android project I use a class method to set a font type to all views here is the method :

```
    public  void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v ) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"font/aFont.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

It is working fine on my fragment except when I change the orientation of device. after that this method not working even by restoring the orientation to portrait!
I tried saveInstanceState (I think it's not about my problem)....
So what is the problem?!

here is my fragment class that I use this method in it.

```
public class aboutUs extends Fragment {

MUF option;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    option = new MUF(getActivity(), getContext());
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aboutus_fragment);
    option.overrideFonts(getContext(), relativeLayout);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onActivityCreated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
    return view;


}


}
```

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria If I do that, It's not working at all!

Comment: option = new MUF(getActivity(), getContext());
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aboutus_fragment);
    option.overrideFonts(getContext(), relativeLayout);

place this code in your onCreateView method

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"//Your fragment's activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

From your AndroidManifest.xml Just remove `"orientation"` and `"screenSize"` from `android:configChanges` and `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` too if added to the activity of your fragment

Comment: I have not this parts in my AndroidManifest.xml!

Comment: oh! then your your activity launch? pls post your manifest code and from which activity your are pushing `aboutUs ` this fragment?